# How can I clear the cache of the workflow designer (where does it cache things)?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, workflow-foundation, designer, workflow-foundation-4

Every time I change some `InArgument` of my `CodeActivity` or an activity defined as an XOML, it takes a couple of restarts of Visual Studio and deleting all the traces of my project's dll on the hard drive (not sure which part actually works) until the changes are reflected in the workflow designer.

Is there some way to clear the cache of the workflow designer / Visual Studio so that the changes I have made for the activities are reflected immediately ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found the reason : I happened to deploy the dll of my project into the PrivateAssemblies folder of visual studio IDE, that has somehow confused the designer. After removing it rebuild works as before..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem is. Normally all I have to do is recompile the assembly and the designer, still open, will see the changes.

Comment: I remember it used to be like that before but now the changes don't have any effect.. even when I drag a new instance of an activity to the designer it still has the old set of attributes, quite weird..